# Lenght of neighboring regions in MEMORY command (linker)

Tags: linker, linker-scripts

I want to declare few regions in linker script, one after another. Do I need to reduce the length by one to avoid overlapping ?

```
MEMORY
{
region_1 :     org = 0x100,   len = 0x100 /* or len = 0xFF ? */
region_2 :     org = 0x200,   len = 0x100 /* or len = 0xFF ? */
region_3 :     org = 0x300,   len = 0x100 /* or len = 0xFF ? */
[...]
}
```

Comment: Imagine you start counting at 0x100 with a length of 0x10 (16 decimal). That is 0x100 0x101 0x102 0x103 0x104 0x105 0x106 0x107 0x108 0x109 0x10a 0x10b 0x10c 0x10d 0x10e 0x10f (a total of 16 values). The next number would start at 0x110. Same applies lengths of 0x100 as well. No, they don't overlap.

Comment: How would you define a region of size 1?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to reduce the length by one to avoid overlapping ?

No. What you are doing is correct.

From GNU Linker manual [Memory Layout](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_mono/ld.html#SEC16) section:

> `len` is the size in bytes of the region

Example:

```
MEMORY
{
region_1 : org = 0x10000000,   len = 1     /* 1 byte */
region_2 : org = 0x20000000,   len = 256K  /* 256 kilobytes */
region_3 : org = 0x30000000,   len = 4M    /* 4 megabytes ? */
[...]
}
```